# add html page to codeigniter project

Tags: php, codeigniter

I crated a simple html page **mypage.html**. It simply post data to **upload.php**
all this run fine.

But now I wanted to add this page in my codeigniter project. But it could not added. How I can add this page to my codeigniter project. such that I only type **mypage.html** in url.

this is error

404 Page Not Found

The page you requested was not found.

Comment: Why aren't you just creating a "regular" CI view?

Comment: sir I am new to codeigniter. and i do not know how this thing in view. please help me out from this problem. and please explain how this is done in view

Comment: you should put your file on view folder and make a function to access that in controller and call the view with that.

Comment: sir when i add mypage.html in view and run from browser following error   :  Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /dvro-local/application/views/mypage.html on this server

Comment: @ Bahrami-Reza  can you give some example code.

Comment: you need to create a function in your controller. an then call it in url

Comment: Go to your .htaccess file and remove "Deny from all". This should fix this problem.

Comment: @OllyTenerife:  when i remove deny for all fromm .htaccess file and run the code again this error come    404 Page Not Found

The page you requested was not found.

Comment: Usman do you have any function in your controller file for call you view ?

Comment: Create a controller, a method within that controller, then load your .html file within that method. See my code below. Make sure your .html file is in the 'Views' folder. Then access via the URL: localhost/controllerName/MethodName (in your case localhost/page/mypage)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a controller, and then load the .html template from that controller.

Example:

Create a controller called 'Page.php'. Create a function within this controller called mypage(). Within mypage(), simply load your template:

```
<?php

class Page extends CI_Controller {

    public function mypage()
    {
        $this->load->view('mypage.html');
    }
}
```

Ensure your .html template is in the 'Views' folder. Then simply access via the browser by entering localhost/page/mypage

Codeigniter provide great docs and tutorials. Check them out here http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/tutorial/static_pages.html

Comment: De nada :) I really recommend having a look at the Codeigniter documentation if you encounter any more problems, the examples and explanations they provide are really useful for beginners.

Comment: thanks. but one problem is that css and js files are not included.

Comment: Are you having problems including your css/js files?

Answer (score 0):

You can make method in you controler. There you load that page like $this->load->view("youpagename"), but before this, change your file  from .html to .php

Comment: thanks. but one problem is that css and js files are not included

Comment: You should create directory alongside your codeigniter folder and place scripts and css there. Then link it from there in your page.